# Слетают шрифты при отправке формы с помощью AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla

При обновлении цены в корзине аяксом, слетают шрифты, подгруженные из *google fonts* в `head`.

Добавьте товар в корзину и обновите количество товара, шрифты слетят.

https://lasercut.spb.ru/pos-materialy/karmany-iz-orgstekla/vertikalnyj-karman-2kh-gibnyj

Для обновления используется следующая функция:

```
function update() {
  var msg   = $('#Cart').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php print SEFLink("index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=cart&task=refresh")?>',
      data: msg,
      success: function(html){
        $('html').html(html);
      },
    });
}
```

Comment: Так а у вас в ответ нормальные данные приходят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что при нажатии на "обновить" вы меняете все содержимое страницы

```js
function update() {
      var msg   = $('#Cart').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/korzina/refresh',
          data: msg,
          success: function(html){
            $('html').html(html);
            $("head").append("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed&subset=cyrillic-ext,latin\" \/>");
            $("head").append("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext\" \/>");
          },
        });

    }
```

либо обновляйте только корзину, либо... location.reload();

Вот нужный вам код, но лучше сделайте что бы сервер отдавал не всю страницу а только нужные данные

```
function update() {
  var msg   = $('#Cart').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/korzina/refresh',
      data: msg,
      success: function(msg){
        var a = $(msg).find('#Cart');
        $('#Cart').html(a.html());
      },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы у вас не слетало ничего в будущих проектах, не указывайте конкретный протокол, не пишите ссылки на библиотеки подключаемые к странице через

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
```

подключайте их так чтобы они работали на обоих протоколах автоматически, пишите так

```
//fonts.googleapis.com/css?
```

и браузер сам подставит нужный протокол, в зависимости от того, как настроен сервер.